# Custom filter in apache shiro

Tags: shiro

I have two set of users one is anonymous and another is valid users (authenticated using cas server). So for anonymous I don't have ticket but for users I have the ticket. But I want to make the resource available to both with some nifty feature will be provided to valid users. My resources are available as REST services. Therefore between two calls (say /foo and /bar. here /foo must be called before /bar) I have to check whether the calling user is same or not?

Therefore I would like to generate a ticket for anonymous user also. so that in /bar, I can check same anonymous user has actually request /bar.

Can anyone suggest how can I solve the above problem using apache shiro.

Also as I have very little knowledge about Apache shiro, I would like to know which one is better apache shiro or spring security (in case of REST services developed using jersey 2)